# Application of Vitali's covering lemma, absolutely continuous function excercise

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that for absolutely continuous function $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=g(x)$ exists almost everywhere and $f(x) = f(-1) + \int_{-1}^{x}g(x)dx$.

I've tried to look for points where $g(x) = \pm \infty$. So let's define $A_M=\left\{x : \lim\sup_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \ge M\right\}$ and observe that a family of segments $[x,x+h]$ such that $f(x+h)-f(x)\ge\frac{Mh}{2}$ is Vitali's covering of $A_M$ so we are able to take subfamily of segments $[x_1,y_1],[x_2,y_2],\ldots$ such that $\mu\left(A_M\setminus\bigcup_{n}[x_n,y_n]\right)=0$. Then $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\ge\frac{M}{2}|x_n-y_n|\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\ge\frac{M}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n-y_n|=\mu(A_M)\frac{M}{2}.$$ Here is the point where I got stuck. Intuitively I'd like to assume that $\forall M>0 \ \ \mu(A_M)>\theta>0$ and contradict it with the assumption that $f$ is absolutely continuous but how to do it? And how to deal with the points where $g(x)$ just doesn't exists?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong there should be an easier way of doing this.

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous, it is the difference of two increasing absolutely continuous functions. Write $f = f_{1} - f_{2}$, where $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are two increasing functions. By Lebesgue's Theorem, which relies on Vitali's Covering Lemma, both $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are differentiable almost everywhere on $(-1,1)$. By linearity (of derivatives), we can conclude the same about $f$.

Another theorem in Measure Theory states that if $\varphi$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ then $\int_{a}^{b}\varphi^{\prime} = \varphi(a) - \varphi(b)$, so that gives the second part.